# How to decode text in html tag

Tags: php, cakephp

I have to decode request data into html tags.
 Code :-

```
#039;&lt;div class=&quot;span12&quot;&gt;
    &lt;!----------------------- Company ------------------&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;row&quot;&gt;
        &lt;div class=&quot;span6&quot;&gt;
            &lt;h3&gt;Company Name&lt;/h3&gt;
            Company Address
        &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;div class=&quot;span6&quot;&gt;
            &lt;h5&gt;INVOICE&lt;/h5&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;
```

I have to decode this in php. what can i do?

Comment: why are you encoding it if you need to decode it?

Comment: Maybe you can use [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) :)

Comment: @MihaiIorga this should be an answer.

Comment: added as an answer :)) [aaaa]

Comment: where do you get this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `html_entity_decode()` ? See the php documents on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
$text = "#039;&lt;div class=&quot;span12&quot;&gt;
&lt;!----------------------- Company ------------------&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;row&quot;&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;span6&quot;&gt;
        &lt;h3&gt;Company Name&lt;/h3&gt;
        Company Address
    &lt;/div&gt;
    &lt;div class=&quot;span6&quot;&gt;
        &lt;h5&gt;INVOICE&lt;/h5&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;br /&gt; &lt;br /&gt;";

$html = html_entity_decode($text);
echo $html;
```

Comment: If there was a problem with the proposed solution; please post it here so that it helps others.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php
or http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

these function will let you decode the html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html_entity_decode`. See http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html_entity_decode()` function to decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `html_entity_decode`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php